# How to switch to grid hotkeys in Stacraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

How can I switch to grid hotkeys in Stacraft 2?

And will it work in multiplayer?

Comment: Menu->options->keybindings?  Is that not working for some reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Menu -> Options -> Hotkeys -> Select the "Grid" option from the dropdown.

Yes it will work in multiplayer.

Answer (score 0):

How to switch to grid hotkeys?  Practice, practice, practice.

Start in a 1v1 AI game, and set the computer on Very Easy.  Play a few games, building as many different units as you can, until you start to get some of the key combinations implanted in your mind.  Then gradually ramp up to Easy, Normal, and on as you get more confident.

Will it work in multiplayer?  Yes, eventually, but you'll definitely want to start with easy AI until you've really cemented those key combos in your brain.  I think you'll find that it'll work *better* in multiplayer, but only after you know those keys like the back of the one hand you're using them with.

Even then, you'll find that in the heat of battle your brain may snap back to SC1 keys.  In that case, make note of which key combo it is, go back into a Very Easy AI game, and build 20 of the thing you got wrong (or issue 20 of the command you got wrong) to retrain yourself.  (You might even try winning the game [it's Very Easy AI, after all] using nothing but whatever units you flubbed, just to really burn their keys into your brain.)